# Why the nav mesh is never working ? I don't see the blue path's after clicking bake

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a character the player :
This is a screenshots of the player Inspector and scene view :

[image: Player inspector settings and scene view]

This screenshot is the continue player inspector settings :

This is a screenshot show the continue player inspector settings :

[image: Player inspector settings]

Then the camera of the player :

[image: Player Camera settings]

The NAVI is positioned a bit in front the player and have a box collider.
The NAVI is important part of the game. For example when getting close to a door when the NAVI enter the door collider area the door will open :

[image: Navi]

Now in this case I don't want the player to be able to walk through walls.
For example this part of the scene this object don't have any collider and now the player can walk through it : Marked the object with red circle : There are many objects like that in the scene :

[image: Object]

Now when going to the Navigation window this is are the settings :
The terrain is the only object that set as static and offmeshlinks and walkable:

[image: Navigation]

All the other objects in the scene that have mesh renderer are NOT marked as navigation static !

Screenshot of the bake tab :

[image: Bake tab]

The areas tab :

[image: Areas]

And last the agents tab :

[image: Agents]

In the end nothing is changed after clicking on the Bake button.
It's thinking and in the end it's not showing the blue path's like it should be. The scene is looks the same like in the first screenshot.

And when running the game the player can keep walking through the objects like in the fifth screenshot where the object is marked with red circle.

Comment: OK the navmesh is only visible in scene not in gameview, if you dont mark items as obstacles it wont know to avoid them, so if the underlying terrain says you can walk through here, thats what it will try and do